# vector<shared_ptr<X>> copying- X constructor called?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

I have a `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>>`

I am looking at the MSVC vector copy constructor implementation. I can see where the vector iterates through the source vector and copies each element. I can see where placement new is called and the shared_ptr constructor is called, but I cannot see the constructor for class `X` being called. I am stepping through the code in debug and I never reach any constructor from class X.

Surely at some point the copy constructor for X is required? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Shared pointers *alias* their pointee: All copies of the pointer point to the same thing. It's not a cloning or deep-copying pointer. It's really rather evil; use it with care!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### If we have the code:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>> vec;
for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
    vec.emplace_back();
```

We would expect the constructor of `X` to be called zero times, the copy constructor of `X` to be called zero times, and the move constructor of `X` to be called zero times.

#### If we have the code:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<X>> vec;
vec.push_back(std::make_shared<X>());
for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i)
    vec.emplace_back();
```

We would expect the constructor of `X` to be called once, and the copy and move constructors of `X` would be called zero times.

#### Why?

We never move or copy `X`. We move and/or copy a `shared_ptr` which may contain a pointer to an `X`. Copying a pointer to `X` does not require us to copy the object.

```
X *obj = new X;
X *ptr_copy = obj;
```

No copy constructor of X is called there either.

Comment: Ahhhhhhh I did wonder if it was because shared_ptr already contains the "data". Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

All copies of shared_ptr point to the same object X. When new copy of shared_ptr created X is not copied.
shared_ptr counts the number of its copies and deletes object when last copy of shared_ptr deleted.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a copy constructor for a std::vector<> contains shared_ptr elements,  it will increase the counter within shared_ptr objects. It will not create a new object of X, instead it will increment the the number of shared objects using the counter within the shared_ptr. So you will not see an execution of constructor of X